# gcc failed with exit status 1 (limits.h doesn't exist error) while installing textract Python3 macOs

Tags: gcc, anaconda, python-3.7, macos-mojave, pdfminer

I am trying to use textract on Python3 on MacOS.

```
`pip install textract`
```

fails with error as following:

`#include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                                 ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

> which gcc

`/usr/local/bin/gcc`

> gcc --version

`gcc (Homebrew GCC 4.9.4_1) 4.9.4
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

I tried to use default gcc compiler after updating through xcode v4.2.0 /usr/bin/gcc but it failed with very similar error: gcc failed with status 1: al.h not found

I've also tried installing gcc from anaconda but that failed with the same error limits.h doesn't exist.

Appreciate your help!

P.S. my ultimate goal is to extract text from Pdf. I tried with PdfMiner.six and PyPdf2 but both of these fail to properly handle spaces. They either remove all whitespaces, concatenating all words or add strange whitespaces.